# Open link from PDF into IE

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdf-generation

I am having a tough time with PDF files opened in IE.  What I need to do is link to a Word document (.doc) file from a PDF document in IE without IE navigating away from the PDF once the link has been clicked.  I am finding that the default behavior of IE is to close the PDF file when you navigate away from it, Firefox will just open the link in a new tab and keep the document open in a separate tab.  I need to find a fix that emulates the firefox behavior that doesn't involve changing the IE settings on the local machine.

To give another example of the functionality I am looking for here is the HTML equivalent:

```
<a href="some_pdf.pdf" target="_blank">Some PDF</a>
```

I need that "_blank" functionality in the PDF document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you should disable IE reusing the window session. The steps are as follows:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Click on the `Tools` button, located in the upper right hand corner of your browser window.
3. When the drop-down menu appears, select `Internet Options`
4. After the Options window opens, switch to the `Advanced` tab
5. Find and make sure the option `Reuse windows for launching shortcuts` is unchecked (it should be under the `Browsing` category)
6. Save and close `Internet Options`, and restart the browser.